# Putting a window air conditioner into an awning window

Tags: hvac

I bought a window air conditioner thinking that I could alter my awning window to accommodate it. I have since discovered that I can't remove the part of the window that swings out or alter it so that it swings out farther. Has anyone found a solution to this, besides using a portable air conditioner, which I don't want to do?

I have thought of building a wooden enclosure for the air conditioner connected to and sealed with the window opening. In other words, a window extension. I would be concerned about a possible fire hazard because of the air (hot?) exhaust and if the exhaust would affect the material that the window is made of.

Comment: A photo of your window would help.

Comment: Most awning windows will not accommodate a window A/C unit. On some, you can disconnect the opening arms and open the window a little more.